# May not respond to +alloc?

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm not sure what the issue is- I'm getting "cannot find interface declaration for Singleton", 
here: @implementation Singleton

and I'm getting "Singleton may not respond to +alloc", 
here: static Singleton *shared;

The .m file

```
#import "Singleton.h"

@implementation Singleton

+(Singleton *) sharedSingleton 
{
    static Singleton *shared;
    if (!shared) {
        shared = [[self alloc] init];
    }

    return shared;
}
```

@end

The .h file

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Singleton : NSObject {

}

+ (Singleton *)sharedSingleton;
@end
```

I just want a basic Singleton class :( They appear as warnings but I want them gone if possible! Hopefully it's not stupid, it's been a long day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try cleaning your project if still it doesn't remove warning then
Change your line from

```
shared = [[self alloc] init];
```

to

```
shared = [[Singleton alloc] init];
```

Comment: sigh, all i needed to do was clean it- thank you. again- long night!

Answer (score 0):

change `self` to `Singleton`, as in `[[Singleton alloc] init]` when setting up your singleton.